# When I reload the pages, the content disappears

Tags: reactjs

I'm basic frontend react js developer and still learning. I map my array from localStorage, the component renders fine, but when I reload the entire render disappears, and when I reload again, the render appears and disappears in the blink of an eye.

I have other components like this, like render arrays, and works fine, no problems, but this component have this strange problem.

The console doesn't show any errors.

Any answer will be appreciated

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
// import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Userinfo() {
    const localUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('log'))
    const { user } = useParams()
    const userInfo = localUsers.filter(x => x.us == user)

    const localPosts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('posts'))
    const userPosts = localPosts.filter(x => x.user == user)

  return (
    <>
        {userInfo.map(x => (
            <div className="userInfo">
                <h1><small>Hola</small> {x.us}</h1>
                <h2><small>Edad </small>{x.age}</h2>
                <h2><small>Posteos de </small>{user}</h2>
            </div>
        ))}
        {userPosts.map(x => (
            <div className="posteo">
            <h1><Link to={`/posts/${x.id}`}>{x.post}</Link></h1>
            <h3>posteo {x.user}</h3>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Userinfo
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code you have shared. you might be setting the localstorage item to empty somewhere else in your app

Comment: store your data using useState then render in your HTML code. also use useEffect to get localstorage data so it will always update when you reload your component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Userinfo() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState([])
  const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = React.useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('log') || '[]')
    const posts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('posts') || '[]')
    const userInfo = users.filter((x: any) => x.us == 'tushar')
    const userPosts = posts.filter((x: any) => x.user == 'trushar')
    setUserInfo(userInfo)
    setUserPosts(userPosts)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {userInfo.map((x: any) => (
        <div className="userInfo">
          <h1><small>Hola</small> {x.us}</h1>
          <h2><small>Edad </small>{x.age}</h2>
          <h2><small>Posteos de </small>{'tushar'}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
      {userPosts.map((x: any) => (
        <div className="posteo">
          <h1>{x.post}</h1>
          <h3>posteo {x.user}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>

  )
}

export default Userinfo
```

Comment: I tried the suggested and works fine, thanks everyone